# Dropdown menu items hidden behind php include

Tags: html, css, superfish

I added a php include to a wordpress page for a hotel booking bar. The booking bar is now hiding my menu dropdown items

Here is a test page with the booking bar: http://www.claridge.com/test/

Here is a page without the bar so you can see the dropdowns: http://www.claridge.com/rooms/

I tried setting z-indexes, but that didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of errors on your test page and that menu is run by script

So something is wrong then it will not run

Fix the below errors or go look at it on your own debug console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.claridge.com/resources/demos/style.css
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined jquery.fancybox.js?ver=1.0:4
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'media' of undefined jquery.fancybox-media.js:39
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'thumbs' of undefined jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js:26
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function jquery.fitvids.js?ver=1.0:78
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined superfish.js?ver=1.0:63
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.claridge.com/resources/demos/style.css
```

For your script error try removing this line

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

you prob need to use jQuery instead of `$`

Also add `alert();`

And if that is working then your code should be running

You are also including many versions of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check [Validator results](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.claridge.com%2Ftest%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3%20http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices#line-245). You'll see you have at least 31 errors (it stops searching at that point). Now, you'll see in lines 245 and 246 you're closing the `</body>`
and `</html>` tags, yet your page barely starts. Fix those issues and it will work fine, basically you're not loading scripts because you're ending your page prematurely